# How do I write an algorithm that allows for no-overflow natural number decrementing?

Tags: algorithm

How can I write a function that takes a string denoting a natural number (>0) such as "100100000000" or "1234567890123456788912345678912345678901234567890" and returns a string denoting the input number decreased by 1? I cannot convert this string to an integer because it could overflow.

I am open to implementing this function in any popular language. I personally know c, C++, Java, javascript, python, and php.

Comment: Python has built-in support for arbitrarily large integers, so no algorithm is needed if you decide on that language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
k=len(x)-1

while(True):
    if x[k]!='0':
        x[k]-=1
        break
    else:
        x[k]='9'
        k--
```

I am leaving boundary conditions for you to work out.

Comment: This will subtract 1111111... from the original number.

Comment: @AdamLiss: looks ok to me (except for the mentioned `k>=0` check).

Comment: @Adam Liss: What? A condition in a loop is perfectly valid and really common code!

Answer (score 1):

Digit **1** is rather easy to decrease. Algorythm is simple:

1. Found any non-zero digit, if any
2. Copy digits before it, if any
3. Decrease found digit
4. Convert digits after it to 9
5. Remove 0 from begining of string

C# code

```
string res = "";
int nonZeroPos = -1;
int pos = s.Length - 1;

// Search for non-zero. TODO: check for digit
while((pos >= 0) && (nonZeroPos == -1))
{
    if(s[pos] != '0')
    {
            nonZeroPos = pos;
    }
    pos--;
}

// TODO: if digit is NOT found

// Non changed part of number
for(int i = 0; i < nonZeroPos; i++)
{
    res += s[i];
}
res += (char)(s[nonZeroPos] - 1);
for(int i = nonZeroPos + 1; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    res += "9";
}

// TODO: kill 0 in the begining
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a near-unlimited capacity and want to write the algorithm yourself, process the string one digit at a time, from right to left, exactly as you would by hand.

Answer (score 0):

In python overflow does not happen, python can hold any big number in practice, In C/C++ it is easy to write a string decrement similar to above algorithm by ElKamina. And Java has a BigInteger class